# Efficiently run over rows in Python dataframe to build a trading signal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I am trying to build indicators and keep track of my position/trades based on a certain signal. The signal is the first column (score). And let's say the trading rules are:

- sell if score > 1
- buy if score < -1
- buy back if have a negative position and score is below 0.5
- sell back if we have a positive position and score is above -0.5

So we can only sell if we have a flat or positive position (so in row 3 we do not sell again)

Example of data is in column 1 and the desired output that I want to build in columns 2 and 3:

```
score        trade     position   
0.9           0          0    
1.1          -1         -1    
1.1           0         -1    
0.9           0         -1    
0.4          +1          0    
0.9           0          0    
1.1          -1         -1  
1.3           0         -1
```

**What I tried**
Using pandas dataframes, I tried building the logic as follows. **Starting with only the score column.**
I would make an indicator column that is 1 if score is above 1. To see if we need to sell.

I would make another column with a rolling sum of 2 rows next to this indicator and another column that is 1 if the previous two columns are 1 (this would mean the signal turned to sell for the first time).

I would then add another column for the cumsum() of that column.

I would then add another column that would be 1 if the cumsum column is -1 and the score is below 0.5. So we know we can buy back.

..
..
this would take a while and then I seem to end up in some kind of selfreferring problem.

Now an alternative would be to just walk over the rows with a function, taking into account the previous value, but I believe this would be quite slow. Especially since I want to do this for a big set of scores.

So can anybody point me in the right direction to do this.

I added a picture that visualizes the intended strategy. The red dots are sells, the green dots are buys. You can only sell if at that moment you are flat (0 position) or long (+1 position) and vice versa.

[image]

Calling the dataframe df. I was building columns like this:

```
df['sell']=-1*(df['score']>1)    
df['signalS']=df['sell'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=2).sum()    
df['signalFiltered']=-1*((df['sell']==-1) & (df['signalS']==-1))    
df['cum']=df['signalFiltered'].cumsum()    
df['buytoclose']=1*((df['cum']==-1) & (df['score']<0.5))    
df['b2c']=df['buytoclose'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=2).sum()    
df['b']=1*((df['b2c']==1) & (df['buytoclose']==1))    
df['pos']=df['signalFiltered'].cumsum()+df['b'].cumsum()
```

But it only works for the start, that is why I think I am running into a reference loop since the sell column needs to be aware of the position and vice versa.

Comment: This is quite broad, can you share the current code?

Comment: Added some code for clarity (?) but not sure it will help.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to design this program” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  Since you have a coding attempt, please post it, and we'll start there.  This is not a site for discussing design options.